# laravel dependency dropdown problem making a ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

i´m having a problem with dependency dropdown in laravel.

```
            <div class="form-group col-md-12{{ $errors->has('professional_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="professional">{{ trans('cruds.session.fields.professional') }}</label>
                <select name="professional_id" id="professional" class="form-control select2">
                    @foreach($professionals as $id => $professional)
                        <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ (isset($session) && $session->professional ? $session->professional->id : old('professional_id')) == $id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $professional }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                @if($errors->has('professional_id'))
                    <em class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ $errors->first('professional_id') }}
                    </em>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12{{ $errors->has('service_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="service">{{ trans('cruds.session.fields.service') }}</label>
                <select name="service_id" id="service" class="form-control select2">
                </select>
                @if($errors->has('service_id'))
                    <em class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ $errors->first('service_id') }}
                    </em>
                @endif
            </div>





    $("#professional").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('admin.services.service_professional') }}?professional_id=" + $(this).val(),
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#service').html(data.html);
            }
        });
    });
```

Route::get('services/service_professional', 'ServiceController@service_professional')->name('services.service_professional');
funcão no controller:

```
public function service_professional(Request $request)
{

    if (!$request->professional_id) {
        $html = '<option value="">'.trans('global.pleaseSelect').'</option>';
    } else {
        $html = '';
        $cities = Service::where('professional_id', $request->professional_id)->get();
        foreach ($cities as $city) {
            $html .= '<option value="'.$city->id.'">'.$city->name.'</option>';
        }
    }

    return response()->json(['html' => $html]);
}
```

error:

/admin/services/service_professional?professional_id=1:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: If you got response 404 then your problem is in Routing or URL. This is server and nothing to do with client UI. Check if service_professional action is called.

Comment: It looks like your route is defined as `services/service_professional`, while you are calling `/admin/services/service_professional` in your JavaScript.

Comment: I'm using a route group to add admin: Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your route is defined as `services/service_professional`, while you are calling `/admin/services/service_professional` in your JavaScript. This is assuming that you have shown us everything in your route definition.

A great way to verify your routing URLs is by calling:

```sh
php artisan route:list
```

You'll get a list of all registered routes, their names (if applicable), and their handlers (either a closure, or a controller action).

Comment: I'm using a route group to add admin: Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {